# scipy parallel interpolation of multiple arrays

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I have multiple arrays of the same dimension, or rather a matrix say

```
data.shape
# (n, m)
```

I want to interpolate the `m-axis` and leave the `n-axis`. Ideally I would get a function which I can call by with an `x-array` of length `n`.

```
interpolated(x)
x.shape
# (n,)
```

I tried

```
from scipy import interpolate
interpolated = interpolate.interp1d(x=x_points, y=data)
interpolated(x).shape
# (n, n)
```

but this evaluates every array at the given point. Is there a better way to do it than ugly loops like

```
interpolated = array(interpolate.interp1d(x=x_points, y=array_) for
                     array_ in data)
array(func_(xi) for func_, xi in zip(interpolated, x))
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `(n,m)`-shaped data is, as you said, is a collection of `n` datasets, each of length `m`. You're trying to pass this an `n`-length `x` array, and expect to obtain an `n`-length result. That is, you're querying the `n` independent datasets at `n` unrelated points.

This makes me believe that you need to use `n` independent interpolators. There is no real benefit in trying to get away with a single call to an interpolation routine. Interpolation routines as far as I know assume that the target of the interpolation is a single object. Either a multivariate function, or a function that has an array-shaped value; in either case you can query the function one (optionally higher-dimensional) point at a time. For instance, multilinear interpolation works across rows of the input, so there's (again, as far as I know) no way to "interpolate linearly along an axis". In your case, there is absolutely no relationship between the rows of your `data`, and there's no relationship between query points, so it's also semantically motivated to use `n` independent interpolators for your problem.

---

As for convenience, you can shove all those interpolating functions into a single function for ease of use:

```
interpolated = [interpolate.interp1d(x=x_points, y=array_) for
                     array_ in data]

def common_interpolator(x):
    '''interpolate n separate datasets at n separate input points'''
    return array([fun(xx) for fun,xx in zip(interpolated,x)])
```

This will allow you to use a single call to `common_interpolator` with an input `array_like` of length `n`.

But since you mentioned it in comments, you can actually make use of `np.vectorize` if you want to add multiple sets if query points to this function. Here's a complete example with three trivial dummy functions:

```
import numpy as np

# three scalar (well, or vectorized) functions:
funs = [lambda x,i=i: x+i for i in range(3)]

# define a wrapper for calling them together
def allfuns(xs):
    '''bundled call to functions: n-length input to n-length output'''
    return np.array([fun(x) for fun,x in zip(funs,xs)])

# define a vectorized version of the wrapper, (...,n) to (...,n)-shape
allfuns_vector = np.vectorize(allfuns,signature='(n)->(n)')

# print some examples
x = np.arange(3)
print([fun(xx) for fun,xx in zip(funs,x)])
# [0, 2, 4]
print(allfuns(x))
# [0 2 4]
print(allfuns_vector(x))
# [0 2 4]
print(allfuns_vector([x,x+10]))
#[[ 0  2  4]
# [10 12 14]]
```

As you can see, all of the above work the same way for a 1d input array. But we can pass a `(k,n)`-shaped array to the vectorized version and it will perform the interpolation row-wise, that is each `[:,n]` slice will be fed to the original interpolator bundle. As far as I know `np.vectorize` is essentially a wrapper for a for loop, but at least it makes calling your functions more convenient.

Comment: I agree, likely `n` independent interpolations have to be performed. However I would still like to 'bundle' the resulting functions into one for convenience. This is simply for readability and to avoid mistakes. But I don't think things like `np.vectorize` work with multiple functions.

Comment: @DerWeh I added my two cents about bundling your functions, especially using np.vectorize. Please let me know how it works for your more complicated example.

Comment: Seems good so far. I just have one convenience issue with it. The using `zip` results in unexpected behavior, if `len(xs) < len(funs)`, as the rest of the function array is truncated. This could lead to errors which are hard to find. Do you know a more elegant solution than manually raising an `ValueError`?

Comment: @DerWeh I believe the "pythonic" solution is exactly manually raising an error. Either manually test for the input size, or put it inside a `try`-`catch` block; it's just a matter of preference of look-before-you-leap vs easier-to-ask-for-permission. Nevermind; as you said, the `zip` works either way, but the result is meaningless. So, I'd definitely test manually and raise an error.

Comment: How would you use `try`-`catch`, there is no exception to catch, is there? -- I would change `np.array([...])` to `np.array(...)`. I think it is more straight forward to use a generator instead of creating an intermediate list.

Comment: @DerWeh thanks, I realized that try-catch is not an option right after I left my comment---see my edit. So I'd do manual checking/raising. As for the genexp: `np.array()` will happily construct a generator-valued array (i.e. one with `dtype=object`), which is not what we need. My hunch is also that even if we _could_ pass a generator, `np.array` would have to construct a list internally, essentially iterating over the generator twice. The first run would provide the `len`: just like how `''.join(gen)` actually runs slightly slower than `''.join(listcomp)`.